# Hash a column in CSV and output in Base64

Tags: python, csv, hash, base64

Still getting my feet wet with Python, but my goal is to read a CSV file and hash a specific column using SHA256 then output in Base64.

Here is an example of the conversion that needs to take place
[image]
This calculator can be found at https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/

Here is the code I have currently

```
import hashlib
import csv
import base64

with open('File1.csv') as csvfile:

    with open('File2.csv', 'w') as newfile:

        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        for i, r in enumerate(reader):
            #  writing csv headers
            if i == 0:
                newfile.write(','.join(r) + '\n')

            # hashing the 'CardNumber' column
            r['consumer_id'] = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(r['consumer_id']).encode('utf-8')).digest()
            
            # writing the new row to the file with hashed 'CardNumber'
            newfile.write(','.join(r.values()) + '\n')
```

The error I receive is

```
r['consumer_id'] = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(r['consumer_id']).encode('utf-8')).digest()
TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing
```

Comment: Just move the close paren `)` after `r["consumer_id"]`: `base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(r['consumer_id'].encode('utf-8'))).digest()`.

Comment: After @MattDMo correction, you will also need to re-home `digest()`

Comment: That returns a new error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Elevate\HashCsv.py", line 64, in <module>
    r['consumer_id'] = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(r['consumer_id'].encode('utf-8'))).digest()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_hashlib.HASH'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, just need to take it a step at a time before doing it all at once to see how it pieces together:

```py
import hashlib
import base64

text = "1234567890"
encoded = text.encode('utf-8')
encoded = hashlib.sha256(encoded).digest()
encoded = base64.b64encode(encoded)
print(text, str(encoded, encoding="utf-8"))
```

That should give you:

```
1234567890 x3Xnt1ft5jDNCqERO9ECZhqziCnKUqZCKreChi8mhkY=
```

As a "one-liner":

```py
r['consumer_id'] = str(base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(r['consumer_id'].encode('utf-8')).digest()), encoding="utf-8")
```

As you can see, your current use is close, but just has some parentheses opportunities to fix.

If you wanted to use this in a loop, say when iterating over a list of words or the rows of a csv you might do this:

```py
import hashlib
import base64

def encode_text(text):
    encoded = text.encode('utf-8')
    encoded = hashlib.sha256(encoded).digest()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(encoded)
    return str(encoded, encoding="utf-8")

words = "1234567890 Hello World".split()
for word in words:
    print(word, encode_text(word))
```

Giving you:

```
234567890 x3Xnt1ft5jDNCqERO9ECZhqziCnKUqZCKreChi8mhkY=
Hello GF+NsyJx/iX1Yab8k4suJkMG7DBO2lGAB9F2SCY4GWk=
World eK5kfcVUTSJxMKBoKlHjC8d3f7ttio8XAHRjo+zR1SQ=
```

Assuming the rest of your code works as you like, then:

```py
import hashlib
import csv
import base64

def encode_text(text):
    encoded = text.encode('utf-8')
    encoded = hashlib.sha256(encoded).digest()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(encoded)
    return str(encoded, encoding="utf-8")

with open('File1.csv') as csvfile:

    with open('File2.csv', 'w') as newfile:

        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        for i, r in enumerate(reader):
            #  writing csv headers
            if i == 0:
                newfile.write(','.join(r) + '\n')

            # hashing the 'CardNumber' column
            r['consumer_id'] = encode_text(r['consumer_id'])
            
            # writing the new row to the file with hashed 'CardNumber'
            newfile.write(','.join(r.values()) + '\n')
```

Comment: That's great for a single entry. I'm working with a CSV with thousands of entries

Comment: I updated the answer with a function that you might use when iterating to convert text into your encoded result.

Comment: You may be spot on, but to be honest I'm more confused now. I don't follow where I would call out the column

Comment: `r['consumer_id'] = encode_text(r['consumer_id'])` according to what I see in your example code.

Comment: alternatively, your one-liner is: `r['consumer_id'] = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(r['consumer_id'].encode('utf-8')).digest())`

Comment: You certainly are a pro at this. The error I'm getting with this is: "newfile.write(','.join(r.values()) + '\n')
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found"

Comment: If you want the string value rather than the bytes from base64 then you can add in a cast to `str()`.  I'll update the answer to do that. The new one liner is in my answer

Comment: I get the same result with the one-liner. I think your comment about str() is likely correct.

Comment: That was the key. Well done sir, much appreciated!

Comment: I updated my answer to cast the result of calling the one-liner or `encode_text()` to be a string rather than bytes if that helps

Comment: The only issue with this output is the data writes as b'THEANSWER'. I'll need to remove the b''

Comment: @JeffIrwin Add an encoding ;-)  `str(base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(r['consumer_id'].encode('utf-8')).digest()), encoding="utf-8")`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JonSG's answer about getting the hashing/encoding correct, I'd like to comment on how you're reading and writing the CSV files.

It took me a minute to understand how you're dealing with the header vs the body of the CSV here:

```py
with open("File1.csv") as csvfile:
    with open("File2.csv", "w") as newfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for i, r in enumerate(reader):
            print(i, r)
            if i == 0:
                newfile.write(",".join(r) + "\n")  # writing csv headers
            newfile.write(",".join(r.values()) + "\n")
```

At first, I didn't realize that calling `join()` on a dict would just give back the keys; then you move on to join the values.  That's clever!

I think it'd be clearer, and easier, to use the complementary DictWriter.

For clarity, I'm going to separate the reading, processing, and writing:

```py
with open("File1.csv", newline="") as f_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_in, skipinitialspace=True)
    rows = list(reader)


for row in rows:
    row["ID"] = encode_text(row["ID"])
    print(row)


with open("File2.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=rows[0])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

In your case, you'll create your writer and need to give it the fieldnames.  I just passed in the first row and the DictWriter() constructor used the keys from that dict to establish the header values.  You need to explicitly call the `writeheader()` method, then you can write your (processed) rows.

I started with this File1.csv:

```
ID, Phone, Email
1234680000000000, 123-456-7890, johnsmith@test.com
```

and ended up with this File2.csv:

```
ID,Phone,Email
tO2Knao73NzQP/rnBR5t8Hsm/XIQVnsrPKQlsXmpkb8=,123-456-7890,johnsmith@test.com
```

That organization means all your rows are read into memory first.  You mentioned having "thousands of entries", but for those 3 fields of data that'll only be a few hundred KB of RAM, maybe a MB of RAM.

If you do want to "stream" the data through, you'll want something like:

```py
reader = csv.DictReader(f_in, skipinitialspace=True)
writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)

writer.writeheader()

for row in reader:
    row["ID"] = encode_text(row["ID"])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

In this example, I passed `reader.fieldnames` to the `fieldnames=` param of the DictWriter constructor.

For dealing with multiple files, I'll just open and close them myself, because the multiple `with open(...) as x` can look cluttered to me:

```py
f_in = open("File1.csv", newline="")
f_out = open("File2.csv", "w", newline="")

...

f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

I don't see any real benefit to the context managers for these simple utility scripts: if the program fails it will automatically close the files.

But the conventional wisdom is to use the `with open(...) as x` context managers, like you were.  You could do nested, like you were, [separate them with a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43130992/246801), or if you have Python 3.10+ use grouping parenthesis for a cleaner look (also in that Q/A).